# CSV parsing program that creates distinct header rows with transaction rows underneath

Tags: python, python-2.x, csv, hash-map

My code reads in the data using `DictReader`, then creates a header row that contains my composite key (PEOPLE_ID, DON_DATE), and then adds various values that are distinct to each section.  The output looks like this:

```
-01- PEOPLE_ID, DON_DATE, etc...
-02- dataline
-02- dataline
-01- ...
etc...
```

I'm looking to possibly simplify or streamline this code, and then could use advice on how to implement robust error-handling throughout.  Here is my program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# pre_process.py
import csv
import sys


def main():
    infile = sys.argv[1]
    outfile = sys.argv[2]
    with open(infile, 'rbU') as in_obj:
        reader, fieldnames = open_reader(in_obj)
        reader = sorted(reader, key=lambda key: (key['PEOPLE_ID'], 
                                                 key['DON_DATE']))
        header_list = create_header_list(reader)
        master_dict = mapData(header_list, reader)
        writeData(master_dict, outfile, fieldnames)


def open_reader(file_obj):
    reader = csv.DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=',')
    return reader, reader.fieldnames


def create_header_list(dict_obj):
    p_id_list = []
    for row in dict_obj:
        if (row['PEOPLE_ID'], row['DON_DATE']) not in p_id_list:
            p_id_list.append((row['PEOPLE_ID'], row['DON_DATE']))
    return p_id_list


def mapData(header_list, dict_obj):
    master_dict = {}
    client_section_list = []
    for element in header_list:
        for row in dict_obj:
            if (row['PEOPLE_ID'], row['DON_DATE']) == element:
                client_section_list.append(row)
        element = list(element)
        element_list = [client_section_list[0]['DEDUCT_AMT'],
                    client_section_list[0]['ND_AMT'],
                    client_section_list[0]['DEDUCT_YTD'],
                    client_section_list[0]['NONDEDUCT_YTD']
                    ]
        try:
            element_list.append((float(client_section_list[0]['DEDUCT_YTD']) +
                                 float(client_section_list[0]['NONDEDUCT_YTD'])
                                 ))
        except ValueError:
            pass

        element.extend(element_list)
        element = tuple(element)
        master_dict[element] = client_section_list
        client_section_list = []
    return master_dict


def writeData(in_obj, outfile, in_fieldnames):
    with open(outfile, 'wb') as writer_outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(writer_outfile, delimiter=',')
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(writer_outfile,
                                     fieldnames=in_fieldnames,
                                     extrasaction='ignore')

        for k, v in in_obj.iteritems():
            writer_outfile.write(' -01- ')
            writer.writerow(k)
            for i, e in enumerate(v):
                writer_outfile.write(' -02- ')
                dict_writer.writerow(e)


def getReconTotals(infile):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Don't reuse names for multiple purposes

Before this line, `reader` is a `DictReader`,
after this line it's a `list`:

> ```
>     reader = sorted(reader, key=lambda key: (key['PEOPLE_ID'], 
>                                              key['DON_DATE']))
> ```

This can be confusing. It would be better to name the result something else.
And it gets worse: this new reader `reader` is passed to `create_header_list` and `mapData` as parameter named "dict_obj",
which further adds to the confusion.

#### Simplify set creation

This function essentially creates a set:

> ```
> def create_header_list(dict_obj):
>     p_id_list = []
>     for row in dict_obj:
>         if (row['PEOPLE_ID'], row['DON_DATE']) not in p_id_list:
>             p_id_list.append((row['PEOPLE_ID'], row['DON_DATE']))
>     return p_id_list
> ```

The `not in` check is inefficient, because it's an \$O(n)\$ operation.

It would be simpler and more efficient to use a `set`:

```
def create_header_list(dict_obj):
    p_id_set = set()
    for row in dict_obj:
        p_id_set.add((row['PEOPLE_ID'], row['DON_DATE']))
    return p_id_set
```

Or even:

```
def create_header_list(dict_obj):
    return set([(row['PEOPLE_ID'], row['DON_DATE']) for row in dict_obj])
```

If the ordering of the elements is important,
then instead of a `set`, you can use an `OrderedDict`,
as suggested by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653887/equivalent-for-linkedhashmap-in-python).

#### Running Python scripts

Not all systems have Python at `/use/bin/python`. The recommended shebang for Python scripts:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

#### Follow PEP8

[PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is the coding style guide for Python.
Among other things,
it recommends using `snake_case` for variable and function names.
Several functions violate that.

Even if you disagree with a specific naming convention,
it's a universal violation of good naming practices to mix two kinds of naming styles in the same program, such as `create_header_list` and `mapData`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  What are O(n) operations, and why are they bad?